# Reorder y axis after geom_bar with position fill in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I have been producing a bar plot in ggplot but fail to reverse the output order of my y axis.

my code:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=time_, fill= factor(class))) +
geom_bar(position = "fill") + scale_y_reverse()
```

when trying scale_y_reverse it do reverse the order, but the percentage of of each of the total is broken.

I have serched sor solutions but don't find any.

Am I missing somthing here??

Have:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5bT6.jpg)

Want:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIgsn.jpg)